# Do we really need the 'concept' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is not every question about some [concept](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concept)? I'm wondering if this is not way too unspecific to be a useful tag at all.

It's a bit like having a 'numbers' tag on Math.SE. I could see the use of 'number-theory' ('concept-theory'?) or specific cases like 'prime-numbers' (are there equivalents for 'concept'?), but 'numbers' or 'concept' just seems a bit too broad.

What do you think? Should the tag be removed?

Comment: I would say remove it -- *unless* the question is actually about the notion of a "concept" (e.g., in Hegel, Leibniz)

Comment: I agree with @JosephWeissman

Answer (score 3):

There is a question [Concept as a Mental Representation](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/concepts-as-mental-representations) that is an example of a question that is about concepts themselves, and just looking through the list there are maybe 2 or 3 others. Seems like we should remove those tags from the other questions.